# Wordpress custom wp_users, wp_usermeta join not ordering properly

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have a custom query to pull users with their user_meta for a statistics plugin I wrote. I am able to select (WHERE) based on a date range, as well as ORDER BY any of the meta fields, however, I cannot do both at the same time. I am losing my mind!! Here is my query (with default variables for reference underneath) ...

```
$getUserData = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT
ID, user_email, user_registered,
first_name.meta_value as first_name,
last_name.meta_value as last_name,
telephone.meta_value as telephone,
country.meta_value as country,
company.meta_value as company,
address.meta_value as address,
city.meta_value as city,
professional_title.meta_value as professional_title,
state.meta_value as state,
areas_of_interest.meta_value as areas_of_interest
FROM wp_users
LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta AS first_name ON first_name.user_id=ID
    AND first_name.meta_key='first_name'
LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta AS last_name ON last_name.user_id=ID
    AND last_name.meta_key='last_name'
LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta AS telephone ON telephone.user_id=ID
    AND telephone.meta_key='telephone'
LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta AS country ON country.user_id=ID
    AND country.meta_key='country'
LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta AS company ON company.user_id=ID
    AND company.meta_key='company'
LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta AS address ON address.user_id=ID
    AND address.meta_key='address'
LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta AS city ON city.user_id=ID
    AND city.meta_key='city'
LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta AS professional_title ON professional_title.user_id=ID
    AND professional_title.meta_key='professional_title'
LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta AS state ON state.user_id=ID
    AND state.meta_key='state'
LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta AS areas_of_interest ON areas_of_interest.user_id=ID
    AND areas_of_interest.meta_key='areas_of_interest'
" . $where . " 
ORDER BY " . $orderBy . " " . $sortOrder . " LIMIT 0, " . $page_limit);

 $where = "WHERE (user_registered >= '" . $_REQUEST['from'] . " 00:00:00' and  user_registered <= '" . $_REQUEST['to'] . " 00:00:00') ";

$orderBy = "user_registered";

$sortOrder = "ASC";
```

Comment: I guess this is one of those questions that people just say ... "next"!

Comment: Since I've never used $wpdb directly and I'm not sure if it does processing, have you tried your query directly in Workbench or command line?

Comment: Need a lot more to go on - this query works fine for me. You'll need to debug it, see what query is actually being run. As well as run this directly from the command line to see if it's WP getting in the way. If so, look into plugins - they can hook into and alter (most) queries that go through get_results.

Comment: I don't like wpdb class for some relatively complex queries. Had many problems with it. This might not be the case, but you may want to try using php mysql(i) or PDO to confirm it is not a wpdb class problem. It's not mandatory to use it, anyway.

Comment: Might be a silly question, but can you confirm that in your testing environment, `$where`, `$orderBy`, `$sortOrder` and `$page_limit` are declared **before** `$getUserData`? Because right now it seems like you will get `...AND areas_of_interest.meta_key='areas_of_interest' ORDER BY   LIMIT 0, `. Also, I would suggest that instead of `$_REQUEST['from']`, you use `$wpdb->escape( $_REQUEST['from'] )`. This way you will be better protected against SQL attacks.

Comment: @JamesHuckabone Debug (`print_r`) the variables you pass to be sure they are what you expect. Tell us if you get a PHP or DB error.

Comment: In order to see any DB errors, place this code above your query: `$wpdb->show_errors();`. This will display any errors that you might have in your query. If you don't see any errors, then your query is correct.

Comment: Sorry for my delay in looking at this!  Ok, so: 1) I'm sure that the variables are declared beforehand. 2) I don't get any ->show_errors() 3) I will work on the other suggestions and get back ...

Comment: Please see my comment below.  I'd love to have a mulligan here but I feel I should assign the points and move on.  The question is, who should I assign them to?  Actually, I think Nikola gave the most helpful answer.  How do I assign you points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hint - [mysql_error()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) telling us that if you place your variables correct you still forgeting to set there **$page_limit**

Comment: mysql_error did not show anything.  But, alas, I am a fool my friends.  For some unexplainable reason I had set the limit to zero, way up in my code.  So, this is why I wasn't getting any errors.  I'm sorry to have wasted everyone's time.\

Comment: actually if you read carefully my comment - i was pointign you about $page_limit =). cheers. good that you solve this yourself =)

Comment: There you go.  Thanks everyone.  Again, sorry for wasting your time.